# Can't Install msysgit/tortoisegit

Tags: windows-7, git, msysgit, tortoise-git

I ran msysGit-netinstall-1.7.0.2-preview20100407-2.exe.
  (http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/downloads/list)
Then I ran TortoiseGit-1.4.4.0-64bit.msi.
  (http://code.google.com/p/tortoisegit/downloads/list)

msysgit was installed in C:\
TortioseGit appears to have been installed in C:\Program Files\TortoiseGit

I have:

- "Git Clone..."
- "Git Create repository here"
- "TortoiseGit"

in Explorer context menu.

When I try to clone, I get "git have not installed" [sic].

- I have tried setting the MSysGit path, in the TortioseGit settings, to everything imaginable. Nothing works.
- Neither C:\Program Files or C:\Program Files (x86) have a Git folder.
- The git command gives "command not found" from both cmd.exe and bash (that msysgit installed)
- I don't not see msysgit in -> Control Panel -> Programs -> Program Features, but I do see TortioseGit in there.

I would like a procedure for verifying that msysgit is properly installed.
A procedure for uninstalling msysgit would be an added bonus.
I would like a procedure for getting TortoiseGit to work.

I am running Windows 7 on a MacBook Pro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The solution:

I was also with the same problem...

I found it: groups.google.com/group/tortoisegit-users/browse_thread/thread/ff1d81f59cd5fe90

Follow Frank's suggestion in the link above; install http://msysgit.googlecode.com/files/Git-1.7.0.2-preview20100309.exe instead of msysgit and be happy :)